# Webpage encoding wrong only on Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a PHP page that takes data from a MySQL database and shows it on the page. 
The database uses Unicode encoding but the table is latin1 with some accented characters in the data set.

The HTML meta tag charset is UTF-8 and all browsers except FF show accented characters properly. I can fix the problem by setting the charset header using PHP. Prior to this no charset header has been set in PHP, so I don't think that is the problem. Even headers_list() shows nothing.

Why would only FF have this problem? When I right click and check the page info, FF shows the encoding of the page to be windows-125. It must be stated that FF does not do this for other pages on the website.

What could be the cause?

Comment: If you lie to browsers about your content encoding you shouldn't be surprised that it breaks. It's not Firefox that has a problem. Don't lie.

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding. Your use "Unicode encoding" seems a chapter name of Unicode standard, which explains many encodings. "Windows-125" is not an encoding. Missing a digit?